Flutter Run Error: SDK Constraint Must Be >=2.12.0 for Null Safety
I'm encountering an error when trying to run my Flutter project. The error message is as follows:
Resolving dependencies...
The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.7.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
The current Dart SDK (3.5.0) only supports null safety.
For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety

I checked my pubspec.yaml file, and the SDK constraint is set to >=2.7.0 <3.0.0.
I am using Dart SDK version 3.5.0.
How can I resolve this SDK constraint issue?
Should I update the SDK constraint in pubspec.yaml? If so, what should it be changed to?
I want to ensure my project is compatible with null safety.
Any guidance on migrating to null safety would also be appreciated.
Thank you!

you have lower bound 2.7.0 but you need 2.12.0 as the error says

I know, please consider question.

I don't want downgrade

in your pubspec.yaml file, change your sdk setting to this:
environment:
  sdk: ^3.5.0


I had another version problem again, Are there any methods to tailor all module version according my flutter sdk version? thanks.

No, not to my knowledge. But I would run flutter pub upgrade --major-versions which would make sure all packages are updated to latest versions. It's also a good idea to install a plugin into your IDE such as flutter-pub-version-checker for Android Studio which helps you keep track of your packages and updates the pubspec.yaml accordingly.
